# output of a program for returning a string literal from a function

Tags: c, string, pointers, literals

```
char* fun()
{
  return("samsung india");
}
main()
{
  printf("%s",printf("electronics")+fun());
}
```

Output: "electronicsia"

could somebody please explain me this output ?

Comment: What stopped you from reading the manual and finding out what the `printf` function does and returns?

Comment: printf("electronics");printf("%s",&("samsung india"[11]));//11:number of output of "electronics"

Comment: it was a question asked by Samsung in an interview. And it gives the o/p I provided. So, could you please explain why this o/p happened ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf("electronics")` sends the output to stdout and returns the number of characters printed, which is 11, and since `fun()` returns a char-pointer, you are adding 11 to that pointer before the outer printf sends it to stdout.

So the inner printf outputs "electronics" and after that the outer printf outputs "ia".

Answer (score 0):

I would say that output can be different on each runtime.. because what happen there:

```
printf("%s",printf("electronics")+fun());
```

assume this: printf("%s", arg); where your arg = printf("electronics")+fun()

arg is suposse to be an char* so the pointer... actually when your arg is evaluated, printf("electronics") provide output electronics and return value 11(number of character which was successfully print), your fun() return char* - pointer to memory which points to samsung india, but you add to that pointer 11, so your pointer will be pointing to the "ia" and this add to the output...

Comment: actually output was the same provided by Samsung interviewer and what I got when I ran the code on my machine. But your explanation is correct. Thanks